# Empty $_POST array but php://input has data

Tags: javascript, php, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and only have minimal experience with php. I've been spending hours scouring the web and looking at other posts similar to my issue and for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to send some info through an XMLHTTPRequest using POST. The data shows up fine when accessing it via php://input, but nothing comes through the $_POST array itself. Why?

I've tried using json_decode, which didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<script>

    var sendstring = "name=The Muffin Man&address=123 Drury Lane, Fairy Town, CA 01234";

    poststuff(sendstring, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            alert("Entry added to database");
        }
        else
        { 
            alert("Failed. Response code is: " + responseCode + ", data: " + data);
        }
    });

    function poststuff(sendstring, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        request.open('POST', "posttofile.php", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send(sendstring);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

posttofile.php:

```
<?php
    $myFile = "data.txt";

    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');

    $postdata = serialize($_POST);

    $phpinputdata = file_get_contents('php://input');

    fwrite($fh, "postdata: " . $post_body . "\nphpinputdata: " . $phpinputdata);

    fclose($fh);
?>
```

data.txt output:

```
postdata: 
phpinputdata: name=The Muffin Man&address=123 Drury Lane, Fairy Town, CA 01234
```

Comment: where are you url encoding your data?

Comment: @madalinivascu I guess I'm not in this version of the code. If I rewrite the first line as var sendstring = encodeURIComponent([stuff]) the problem still persists with the $_POST array being empty. I don't really understand what's necessary for encoding and when very well. Is there anything you would suggest?

Comment: You should only encode the key and the value (not the = sign). And if you then post the data, you should be able to use `$_POST` straight off. No need to use `php://input` if you're posting the data as form-url-encoded. PHP will handle all that for you.

Comment: Btw, you're setting `$postdata` but are trying to write an undefined variable `$post_body`, which could be reason the $_POST seems empty when you write it

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Wow, I think you figured it out, thank you! Yeah, I definitely had a problem before mixing up my variables in the PHP file that I built quickly to demonstrate my problem, but that was an issue as well. Encoding the keys and values before putting them together did the trick. Do you know of any well-regarded references that demonstrate this? I didn't see anything that clearly laid this out while learning how to send an XMLHTTPRequest using POST.